# Which FaaS provide higher /tmp storage space for per function execution?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, openwhisk, serverless-architecture, faas

We are developing a video streaming platform

We need to convert video files uploaded by the user which is in cloud storage

We decided to use AWS Lamda  for that purpose .

But later we find out lambda can't process file above 512 MB since the allocated /TMP folder max size is 512 MB

Our video files in S3 bucket is above 1 GB

So we need to find out other FaaS who provide /TMP space atleast 2 GB ?

So please suggest a faas provider who give atleast 
2 GB

Note : if there is none , please suggest me a alternative way

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a Lambda + Fargate solution for this one.

The Lambda can be triggered by an S3 upload event (alternatively, it can be another event source as long as it gets the S3 path to the file).

This Lambda then triggers a Fargate task given the S3 path to the video file.

A good example for this can be seen in https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-application-for-long-running-process-fargate-lambda/.

Comment: Good. But we have to pay for fargate also . We are tight in the budget. If only FaaS it would be great